# checkbox in listview for multiple selection of contacts

Tags: android, listview

I had tried to to put checkbox in listview through layout inflator and I got success but the problem is when I select the multiple contacts there is no problem but when I deselect it & when I scroll down & then go back to that deselected checkbox its get automatically selected...

```
public class Contactlist_selfActivity extends ListActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

private ArrayList<contact> contact_list = null;
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog = null;
private contactAdapter mContactAdapter = null;
private Runnable mViewcontacts = null;
private SparseBooleanArray mSelectedContacts = new SparseBooleanArray();
private ArrayList<contact> items;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    contact_list = new ArrayList<contact>();
    this.mContactAdapter = new contactAdapter(this, R.layout.listview,
            contact_list);
    ListView lv = getListView();
    setListAdapter(this.mContactAdapter);
    lv.setItemsCanFocus(false);
    lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    // }
    mViewcontacts = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            getContacts();
        }
    };

    Thread thread = new Thread(null, mViewcontacts, "ContactReadBackground");
    thread.start();
    mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Contactlist_selfActivity.this,
            "Please Wait...", "Retriving Contacts...", true);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private void getContacts() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try {

        String[] projection = new String[] {
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER,
                ContactsContract.Contacts._ID };

        Cursor mCursor = managedQuery(
                ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, projection,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=?",
                new String[] { "1" },
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);

        while (mCursor.moveToNext()) {
            contact contact = new contact();

            String contactId = mCursor.getString(mCursor
                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

            contact.setContactName(mCursor.getString(mCursor
                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)));
            contact_list.add(contact);
        }
        mCursor.close();

        runOnUiThread(returnRes);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Log.d("getContacts", e.getMessage());
    }
}

public class contactAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<contact> {
    private int[] isChecked;

    public contactAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            ArrayList<contact> items1) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items1);
        items = items1;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final int position_clicked = 0;
        // Log.i("asd", "getView :" + getItem(position));

        if (convertView == null) {

            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.listview, parent, false);
        }

        contact contacts = items.get(position);
        isChecked = new int[items.size()];

        if (contacts != null) {
            final CheckBox nameCheckBox = (CheckBox) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            nameCheckBox.setChecked(mSelectedContacts.get(position));

            for (int i = 0; i < isChecked.length; i++) {

            }

            if (nameCheckBox != null) {
                nameCheckBox.setText(contacts.getContactName());
            }

            nameCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    isChecked[position_clicked] = position;
                    Log.d("position", String.valueOf(position));
                }
            });

        }

        return convertView;
    }
}

private Runnable returnRes = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (mProgressDialog.isShowing())
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        mContactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

i found the answer....
i had just taken a new variable in contact class...

```
public class PlanetsActivity extends Activity {
private ListView mainListView;
private Contact[] contact_read;
private Cursor mCursor;
private ArrayAdapter<Contact> listAdapter;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Find the ListView resource.
    mainListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainListView);

    mainListView
            .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View item,
                        int position, long id) {
                    Contact planet = listAdapter.getItem(position);
                    planet.toggleChecked();
                    ContactViewHolder viewHolder = (ContactViewHolder) item
                            .getTag();
                    viewHolder.getCheckBox().setChecked(planet.isChecked());
                }
            });

    // Throw Query and fetch the contacts.

    String[] projection = new String[] { Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER,
            Contacts._ID, Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME };

    mCursor = managedQuery(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, projection,
            Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=?", new String[] { "1" },
            Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);

    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
        contact_read = new Contact[mCursor.getCount()];

        // Add Contacts to the Array

        int j = 0;
        do {

            contact_read[j] = new Contact(mCursor.getString(mCursor
                    .getColumnIndex(Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)));
            j++;
        } while (mCursor.moveToNext());

    } else {
        System.out.println("Cursor is NULL");
    }

    // Add Contact Class to the Arraylist

    ArrayList<Contact> planetList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    planetList.addAll(Arrays.asList(contact_read));

    // Set our custom array adapter as the ListView's adapter.
    listAdapter = new ContactArrayAdapter(this, planetList);
    mainListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}

/** Holds Contact data. */
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static class Contact {
    private String name = "";
    private boolean checked = false;

    public Contact() {
    }

    public Contact(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Contact(String name, boolean checked) {
        this.name = name;
        this.checked = checked;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return checked;
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        this.checked = checked;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    public void toggleChecked() {
        checked = !checked;
    }
}

/** Holds child views for one row. */
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static class ContactViewHolder {
    private CheckBox checkBox;
    private TextView textView;

    public ContactViewHolder() {
    }

    public ContactViewHolder(TextView textView, CheckBox checkBox) {
        this.checkBox = checkBox;
        this.textView = textView;
    }

    public CheckBox getCheckBox() {
        return checkBox;
    }

    public void setCheckBox(CheckBox checkBox) {
        this.checkBox = checkBox;
    }

    public TextView getTextView() {
        return textView;
    }

    public void setTextView(TextView textView) {
        this.textView = textView;
    }
}

/** Custom adapter for displaying an array of Contact objects. */
private static class ContactArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contact> {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ContactArrayAdapter(Context context, List<Contact> planetList) {
        super(context, R.layout.simplerow, R.id.rowTextView, planetList);
        // Cache the LayoutInflate to avoid asking for a new one each time.
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Contact to display
        Contact planet = (Contact) this.getItem(position);
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(position));

        // The child views in each row.
        CheckBox checkBox;
        TextView textView;

        // Create a new row view
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simplerow, null);

            // Find the child views.
            textView = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.rowTextView);
            checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.CheckBox01);

            // Optimization: Tag the row with it's child views, so we don't
            // have to
            // call findViewById() later when we reuse the row.
            convertView.setTag(new ContactViewHolder(textView, checkBox));

            // If CheckBox is toggled, update the Contact it is tagged with.
            checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                    Contact contact = (Contact) cb.getTag();
                    contact.setChecked(cb.isChecked());
                }
            });
        }
        // Reuse existing row view
        else {
            // Because we use a ViewHolder, we avoid having to call
            // findViewById().
            ContactViewHolder viewHolder = (ContactViewHolder) convertView
                    .getTag();
            checkBox = viewHolder.getCheckBox();
            textView = viewHolder.getTextView();
        }

        // Tag the CheckBox with the Contact it is displaying, so that we
        // can
        // access the Contact in onClick() when the CheckBox is toggled.
        checkBox.setTag(planet);

        // Display Contact data
        checkBox.setChecked(planet.isChecked());
        textView.setText(planet.getName());

        return convertView;
    }

}

public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
    return contact_read;
}
```

}

Comment: i am also facing similar problems, can you please post your project in a zip file here.

Comment: i tried using the same code but i am getting errors in eclipse while using it.. pls post the project if you have in archive

Comment: one question, how would I call this with an intent for result? After a user selects some contacts, I want to read these contacts in the activity that calls this activity. Will you please show the code to do that? (may be @TapanDesai did it?)

Comment: how to navigate the selected contacts into the next class.

Answer (score 2):

The cause of this is that when you call `nameCheckBox.setChecked()` in code `OnClickListener()` awakes and run its code. I had the same problem an solved in just setting `OnClickListener(null)` before set a checkbox checked or not.

Comment: if i pass null at onClick then how it get that which item is clicked..???
& can u elaborate more wht to do exactly..???
& thenx..

Comment: you should pass null at onClick() before you call setChecked() and then you should pass the method in at onClick();

Comment: in your code it may look like: nameCheckBox.setOnClickListener(null); nameCheckBox.setChecked(mSelectedContacts.get(position));

Answer (score 2):

nameCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                isChecked[position_clicked] = position;
                Log.d("position", String.valueOf(position));
            }
        });
```

this code in add more one arre list in stores all position and add or remove both said 
fast add ,second remove.
and used to list in position your other method

Comment: but when i scroll down or up if i had deselected contacts get selected..
i got the idea wht u said but as it is getting selected how to get its state as deselected..???