# Sample Project to select multiple contacts

Tags: android, checkbox, android-listview

I want my app to operate such that activity A starts activity B in an intent for result, where activity B is the list view where user selects multiple contacts. Then in activity A, I want to be able to extract the phone numbers in an ArrayList. There are many questions and answers around this issue on Stack Overflow. To list two:

- [using checkbox to filter contacts and get phone number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450058/using-checkbox-to-filter-contacts-and-get-phone-number/10105655#10105655)
- [checkbox in listview for multiple selection of contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834723/checkbox-in-listview-for-multiple-selection-of-contacts)

As one still relatively new to Android development, I find the dispersed code difficult to assemble. So my question: Does anyone have a simple project that does what I seek complete, that they don't mind sharing in a zip file? In the last response in [using checkbox to filter contacts and get phone number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450058/using-checkbox-to-filter-contacts-and-get-phone-number/10105655#10105655) the guy claims to have such a zip project, but when I follow the link, the secondary link that should lead to the project was broken.

If someone does agree to provide a link, please let it not be a partial answer. I figure the task is simple to someone who has done it before: It's two activities, where one is a ListView allowing users to select contacts and the other is a view that displays the selected contacts. In fact, the other does not even have to display the contacts in a view, a simple println to the LogCat will suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/iamporus/AndroWorks/tree/master/ContactSelector) might help you. It is not what you're exactly looking for but it will give you an idea to start working with.
I've used `Loaders` to fetch contacts from phone directory and performing search operations on it. You can use the same `Loader` to populate a `ListView` containing `TextView` (name/number) and `CheckBox` pair as list item. You can maintain a `HashMap` of position vs contact number for keeping track of selected contacts.
Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

The updated link is [here.](https://github.com/iamporus/AndroWorks/archive/master.zip)

Comment: Awesome! +1. Do you mind making it available for zip download? I am usually able to click on a zip icon to get a project, I don't see one next to yours!

Comment: @SimoneCasagranda do you mind fixing your link, too? Maybe like this link -- in a zip?

Comment: I see the zip icon. Too bad I can't give you another +1! Thanks. (I don't even know if it works yet, just happy to see an example that I can hack thru)